# How to change `DateTime` from `df1` to `DateTime2` from `df2` when `df1$DateTime==df2$DateTime`. For the rest of rows of `df1` I subtract 60s

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have one dataframe `df1` which summarises different info (i.e. `Depth`) overtime (`DateTime`). As an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(DateTime=c("2017-08-12 10:18:21.937","2017-08-12 11:43:56.937","2017-08-12 12:22:16.937","2017-08-12 13:24:43.937","2017-08-12 14:35:14.937","2017-08-12 15:48:28.937"),
                 Depth=c(24,12,35,54,13,32))
df1$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(df1$DateTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC")
df1

df1

                 DateTime Depth
1 2017-08-12 10:18:21.937    24
2 2017-08-12 11:43:56.937    12
3 2017-08-12 12:22:16.937    35
4 2017-08-12 13:24:43.937    54
5 2017-08-12 14:35:14.937    13
6 2017-08-12 15:48:28.937    32
```

In other dataframe `df2` I have filtered `df1` and I have calculated a new `DateTime` (called `DateTime2`) for the remaining rows, getting two different times in `df2` (`DateTime` and `DateTime2`). That's an example of what I would get:

```
df2 <- data.frame(DateTime=c("2017-08-12 11:43:56.937","2017-08-12 14:35:14.937"),
                  DateTime2=c("2017-08-12 11:41:48.337","2017-08-12 14:33:23.476"),
                  Depth=c(12,13))
df2$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(df2$DateTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC")
df2$DateTime2 <- as.POSIXct(df2$DateTime2, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC")

df2

                DateTime                DateTime2 Depth
1 2017-08-12 11:43:56.937 2017-08-12 11:41:48.336    12
2 2017-08-12 14:35:14.937 2017-08-12 14:33:23.476    13
```

What I want is to change the `DateTime` in `df1` for the rows in which `df1$DateTime` and `df2$DateTime` coincide, and changing the value of `df1$DateTime` for `df2$DateTime2`. I also want to substract 60 seconds for the rest of rows for which `df1$DateTime` and `df2$DateTime` don't coincide. I would expect this:

```
df1
                 DateTime Depth
1 2017-08-12 10:17:21.937    24
2 2017-08-12 11:41:48.336    12
3 2017-08-12 12:21:16.937    35
4 2017-08-12 13:23:43.937    54
5 2017-08-12 14:33:23.476    13
6 2017-08-12 15:47:28.937    32
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `left_join` by `"DateTime"` and `"Depth"` and then use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by = "DateTime") %>%
   mutate(DateTime = coalesce(DateTime2, DateTime), 
         DateTime = if_else(is.na(DateTime2), DateTime - 60, DateTime)) %>%
   rename(Depth = Depth.x) %>%
   select(names(df1))

#             DateTime Depth
#1 2017-08-12 10:17:21    24
#2 2017-08-12 11:41:48    12
#3 2017-08-12 12:21:16    35
#4 2017-08-12 13:23:43    54
#5 2017-08-12 14:33:23    13
#6 2017-08-12 15:47:28    32
```

Comment: I guess that now that I have corrected my mistake about `DateTime` in `df1`, I can leave out `Depth` from the code, can't I?

Comment: I forgot to include in my question that I also wanted that for the rest of rows of `df1` for which `DateTime` doesn't coincide with `DateTime` of `df2`, I want to subtract 60 seconds. I am going to include this in the post, do you know how to do it? I guess it is easy for you. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `left_join` from `dplyr` package:

```
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = 'Depth') %>%
  mutate(DateTime.x = if_else(!is.na(DateTime2), DateTime2, DateTime.x - 60)) %>%
  select(DateTime = DateTime.x, Depth)

# DateTime Depth
# 1 2017-08-12 10:17:21    24
# 2 2017-08-12 11:41:48    12
# 3 2017-08-12 12:21:16    35
# 4 2017-08-12 13:23:43    54
# 5 2017-08-12 14:33:23    13
# 6 2017-08-12 15:47:28    32
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it necessary to include 'Depth' in the code? I mean, in this example, 'Depth' doesn't have any utility althought it is true that if 'df1$DateTime == df2$DateTime', then, 'df1$Depth == df2$Depth'.

Comment: @Dekike I think it is necessary because row 1 and 2 have the same `DateTime` in `df1` but value is changed only for row 2. Why?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake... I didn't change `DateTime` in row 1 for `df1`. I have already changed it. Can we do it without using `Depth`? I mention that because in my real data, the column `Depth` doesn't exist. I included it like an example of what there is other variables in the dataframe.

Comment: @AlexB, thaks for your reply. As I mentioned to Ronak Shah, I forgot to mention that for the rest of rows of `df1` for which `DateTime` doesn't match with `DateTime` of `df2`, I want to subtract 60 seconds from them. Is it easy to include this in your proposed code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`'s update join:

```
setDT(df1)[, DateTime := DateTime - 60L][
    setDT(df2), on=.(DateTime), DateTime := i.DateTime2]
```

output:

```
              DateTime Depth
1: 2017-08-12 10:17:21    24
2: 2017-08-12 11:42:56    12
3: 2017-08-12 12:21:16    35
4: 2017-08-12 13:23:43    54
5: 2017-08-12 14:34:14    13
6: 2017-08-12 15:47:28    32
```